# Using useDelimiter() in Java to isolate a piece of text

Tags: java

I have a text file with content that looks like this:

```
   Event=ThermostatNight,time=0
   Event=LightOn,time=2000
   Event=WaterOff,time=8000
   Event=ThermostatDay,time=10000
   Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5
   Event=WaterOn,time=6000
   Event=LightOff,time=4000
   Event=Terminate,time=12000
```

I have to use a Scanner to grab the file and then loop through each of the lines of text and isolate each event. For example I need to isolate "ThermostatNight" in the first line and then put it in an array, the next one would be "LightOn", and so on.  It's a small piece of a large project that I am working on for an intermediate Java course. I have been able to get exactly the opposite of what I want with the useDelimiter argument shown below. Is there a quick fix to this. Note that I must use the useDelimiter() method.

```
 public void readFile2() {
     array2 = new ArrayList<String>();  
     while (s.hasNext()) {
        s.useDelimiter("=(.*?),");
        array2.add(s.next());
         }
```

Comment: can you explain your regular expression that you used in your useDelimiter function?

Comment: The ".*?" matches any character (except newline).It is basically saying ignore everything between the "=" and the "," characters.

Comment: don't u need whatever between = and ,?

Comment: yeah... that's why I wanted to somehow take the opposite of it. I thought maybe there was a way to do that. I'm not very experienced with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiples delimiter.

```
//scanner.useDelimiter("Event=|,time=([0-9]*)");
scanner.useDelimiter("Event=|,(.)+[\\r\\n]*Event=|,(.)+[\\r\\n]*");

//for better you can use this

//scanner.useDelimiter("Event=|,time=([0-9]**)[\\r\\n]**Event=|,time=([0-9]*)");

while (scanner.hasNext()) 
{
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Comment: I added "rings=5" to the text file(see edit). I then added a "|,rings=([0-9]*)" into the delimiter. It works but I get a blank space in the array now:[ThermostatNight, LightOn, WaterOff, ThermostatDay, Bell, ,                      , WaterOn, LightOff, Terminate, FansOn, FansOff,

Comment: you missing 1 delimiter ",time=([0-9]*),rings=([0-9]*)[\\r\\n]*Event=".
delimiter is the string you want to skip to next thing you want.

Comment: One optimization for you scanner.useDelimiter("Event=|,(.)+[\\r\\n]*Event=|,time=[0-9]+");

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best , but it will work 
Since you have requirement to use only useDelimeter and if the structure not changed.
then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/xxx/text.txt"));
        sc.useDelimiter(",time=(.*?)\\nEvent=");
        ArrayList<String> eventlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        String tmp = null;
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            tmp = sc.next();
            tmp = tmp.split("=")[1]; // Just First line
        }
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            eventlist.add(tmp);
            System.out.println(tmp); // for test only remove it
            tmp = sc.next();
        }
        tmp = tmp.split(",")[0];
        eventlist.add(tmp);
        System.out.println(tmp); // for test only , remove it
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```